# How to display child items of its respective group item in another listview

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I want to display the child items of its respective group item available in expandable listview into seperate listview.

I have done the following,

```
package com.example.demo_data1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class DrawerLayoutTest extends Activity implements OnChildClickListener {

private DrawerLayout drawer;
private ExpandableListView drawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_layout_test);

    setGroupData();
    setChildGroupData();

    initDrawer();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer_layout_test, menu);
    return true;
}

private void initDrawer() {
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    drawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    drawerList.setAdapter(new NewAdapter(this, groupItem, childItem));

    drawerList.setOnChildClickListener(this);

    // actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer,
    // R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.open_drawer,
    // R.string.close_drawer) {
    // public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    // getActionBar().setSubtitle("open");
    // }
    //
    // /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
    // public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    // getActionBar().setSubtitle("close");
    // }
    //
    // };
    //
    // drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

}

public void setGroupData() {
    groupItem.add("TECHNOLOGY");
    groupItem.add("MOBILE");
    groupItem.add("MANUFACTURER");
    groupItem.add("EXTRAS");
}

ArrayList<String> groupItem = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Object> childItem = new ArrayList<Object>();

public void setChildGroupData() {
    /**
     * Add Data For TecthNology
     */
    ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Java");
    child.add("Drupal");
    child.add(".Net Framework");
    child.add("PHP");
    childItem.add(child);

    /**
     * Add Data For Mobile
     */
    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Android");
    child.add("Window Mobile");
    child.add("iPHone");
    child.add("Blackberry");
    childItem.add(child);
    /**
     * Add Data For Manufacture
     */
    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("HTC");
    child.add("Apple");
    child.add("Samsung");
    child.add("Nokia");
    childItem.add(child);
    /**
     * Add Data For Extras
     */
    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Contact Us");
    child.add("About Us");
    child.add("Location");
    child.add("Root Cause");
    childItem.add(child);
}


public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    switch (groupPosition)
    {
    case 0:
            switch (childPosition)
            {
            case 0:
               MainActivity();
               break;
            case 1:
                //
            }

    }
    return false;
}

private void MainActivity(){
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
}
}
```

Now here in the above code the child items are getting displayed below the group item in same listview instead i want to display the child items in different listview next to group item listview.

Please help me with this, stuck from a long time.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: use child arraylist for another listview

Comment: could you help me with the logic or certain example.

Comment: what you want exactly ? when you click you gruop item then open new activity and there a listview ?

Comment: No no it doesnt open a new activity when i click on group item the child item should display in same activity but instead opening below the group item in same listview it should be displayed in another listview in same activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.listtest.MainActivity" >




<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <!-- Drawer Content -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation menu -->

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_child"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
Fragment fragment = null;
ListView mainlist;
ArrayList<String> formain = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mainlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_child);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerListener);
//  childlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    formain.add("TECHNOLOGY");
    formain.add("MOBILE");
    formain.add("MANUFACTURER");
    formain.add("EXTRAS");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,formain);
    mainlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mainlist);
    mainlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String getGroup = formain.get(arg2);
            if (getGroup == "TECHNOLOGY"){
                fragment = new TechnologyFragment(); 
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mainlist);
            }
            if (getGroup == "MOBILE"){
             //fragment for mobile
            }
            if (getGroup == "MANUFACTURER"){
                //fragment for manufacturer
            }
            if (getGroup == "EXTRAS"){
            //fragment for extras
            }


        }
    });

}
private DrawerListener mDrawerListener = new DrawerListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int status) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float slideArg) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    }
};
}
```

**technology_fragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**TechnologyFragment.java**

```
public class TechnologyFragment extends Fragment {

ListView techlist;
ArrayList<String> forchild = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.technology_fragment, null);
    techlist = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    forchild.add("Java");
    forchild.add("Drupal");
    forchild.add(".Net Framework");
        forchild.add("PHP");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,forchild);
        techlist.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}

}
```

Comment: here the problem is that every time i click the group item the child items get repeated multiple times it should not happen instead it should hide the child items when i click the group item second time.

Comment: @Jigarpatel .. you have manage code acc to your need ... expand `if` condition for all group item and clear listview with every click ..

Comment: The listview should be hidden like navigation drawer and should appear on slide of screen

Comment: then add listview in navigation drawer ... and take frame layout ... make fragment for each group item and take listview in each fragment with its adapter

Comment: please help me with the same i am facing difficulties solving the same please help me with the logic

Comment: hey buddy in main activity i am getting this error `The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Fragment)`

Comment: in main activity **import**

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener;`
in TechnologyFragment **import**
`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72117/discussion-between-sukhwant-singh-grewal-and-jigar-patel).

Comment: i wanna discuss smethng more please checkout the chat

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a ExpandableListView make use of a Normal ListView and fragments.

Show the parent List in Fragment 1 and clicking an item in parent 1 will show fragment 2 which has Child items in a list.

Comment: could u please post some code regarding the same, sry to bother u but i am a bit new at this.